# Hash replacement with regular expression not working

Tags: php, regex

In this file I would like to change the UNDER_CONSTRUCTION_HASH with another 
hash, i do that with a regular expression.

File:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"

UNDER_CONSTRUCTION_HASH=y$TwrFXK90UkJ4pq4grH1/hevPgkdOE4lEmPI9QbhVnwH1UEyYr/zA2
```

I would like to replace the `UNDER_CONSTRUCTION_HASH`with another one:

```
$2y$10$TwrFXK90UkJ4pq4grH1/hevPgkdOE4lEmPI9QbhVnwH1UEyYr/zA2
```

My code together looks like this:

```
$envContent = $this->filesystem->get($envPath);
$regex = '/UNDER_CONSTRUCTION_HASH=[^\s]+/';
$newLine = sprintf('UNDER_CONSTRUCTION_HASH=%s', $hash);

if (preg_match($regex, $envContent)) {
    var_dump($newLine);
    $envContent = preg_replace($regex, $newLine, $envContent);
} else {
    $envContent .= "\n".$newLine."\n";
}
```

The result is this:

```
UNDER_CONSTRUCTION_HASH=y$TwrFXK90UkJ4pq4grH1/hevPgkdOE4lEmPI9QbhVnwH1UEyYr/zA2
```

instead of this:

```
UNDER_CONSTRUCTION_HASH=$2y$10$TwrFXK90UkJ4pq4grH1/hevPgkdOE4lEmPI9QbhVnwH1UEyYr/zA2
```

What could be wrong here?

My package: https://github.com/larsjanssen6/underconstruction

Comment: is `$hash` assignment set in double quotes? if it is, then there's your problem. Use single quotes. The dollar signs mean something in PHP, which it thinks you have a variable already set for it.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner thanks but that's not the case. It's single quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a matter of escaping your dollar signs.

When `$hash` is injected into `$newLine` and used as the replacement parameter of `preg_replace()`, the function is assuming `$2` and `$1` are capture group references.  You will need to park slashes in front of them to have them treated literally.

Here's a re-write:

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Iv6mW))

```
$envContent='MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"

UNDER_CONSTRUCTION_HASH=y$TwrFXK90UkJ4pq4grH1/hevPgkdOE4lEmPI9QbhVnwH1UEyYr/zA2';

$hash = '$2y$10$TwrFXK90UkJ4pq4grH1/hevPgkdOE4lEmPI9QbhVnwH1UEyYr/zA2';
$pattern = '/UNDER_CONSTRUCTION_HASH=\S+/';
$replace = "UNDER_CONSTRUCTION_HASH=".str_replace('$','\$',$hash);  // <-- escape your dollar signs
$newLine = "UNDER_CONSTRUCTION_HASH=$hash";

$envContent = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $envContent, -1, $count);
if(!$count){
    //echo "no replacement made\n";
    $envContent .= "\n".$newLine."\n";
}

echo $envContent;
```

Output:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"

UNDER_CONSTRUCTION_HASH=$2y$10$TwrFXK90UkJ4pq4grH1/hevPgkdOE4lEmPI9QbhVnwH1UEyYr/zA2
```

Comment: Pleasure is mine.  As a bonus, I've reduced your regex function calls down to one.